# Data not being saved in my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I hope you are doing great. I'm having a problem where I cannot insert data into my database. There are multiple reasons to why that happens so don't consider it a duplicate question please. I checked my code. For one table it saves the data but for this table. It displays that the same page was not found and no data is saved on the local database. I hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance. :)
Here are some useful pieces of code:

```
    <?php
include 'Header.php';
?>
<style>
    #first {
        //margin-right: 100%;
        //clear: both;

    }
    #first > img {
        display: inline-block;
        //float: left;
    }
    #first > p {
        //float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        //margin-left: 60px;
        //margin-bottom: 120px;
    }

</style>
<!-- Post content here -->

<!-- Then cmments below -->
<h1>Comments</h1>
<!--<?php ?>
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    echo '<p class="error"> Error has occured</p>';

    include 'footer.html';

    exit();
}

$db = new Database();
  $dbc = $db->getConnection();

  $display = 10; //number of records per page
  $pages;

if(isset($_GET['p']) ) //already calculated
{
    $pages=$_GET['p'];  
}
else
{
//use select count() to find the number of users on the DB    
    $q = "select count(comment_id) from comments";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records=$row[0];

    if($records > $display ) //calculate the number of pages we will need
      $pages=ceil($records/$display);  
    else
      $pages = 1;
}

//now determine where in the database to start 
if(isset($_GET['s']) ) //already calculated
   $start=$_GET['s'];  
else
    $start = 0;

 //use LIMIT to specify a range of records to select 
 // for example LIMIT 11,10 will select the 10 records starting from record 11
  $q = "select * from users order by $orderby LIMIT $start, $display";

  $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

/*if ($r)
{*/

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id= '" + + "'");
//0 should be the current post's id
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
?>
<div class="comment">
By: <!--<?php /* echo $row->author; //Or similar in your table ?>
  <p>
  <?php echo $row->body; ?>
  </p>
  </div>
  <?php
  /*} */
?>*/-->
<h1>Leave a comment:</h1>
<form action="Comment.php" method="post">
    <!-- Here the shit they must fill out -->
    <input type="text" name="comment" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert"/>
</form>';

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $comment = '';

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST['comment']))
        $errors[] = 'You should enter a comment to be saved';
    else
        $comment = trim($_POST['comment']);



    if (empty($errors)) {
        include 'Comments_1.php';
        $comment_2 = new Comments();
        $errors = $comment_2->isValid();
        $comment_2->Comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
        $comment_2->UserName = hamed871;
        $comment_2->Video_Id = 1;
        if ($comment_2->save()) {
            echo '<div class="div_1"><div id="div_2">' .
            '<h1>Thank you</h1><p> your comment has been'
                    . ' posted successfully</p></div></div>';
        }
    }
//First check if everything is filled in
    /* if(/*some statements *//* )
      {
      //Do a mysql_real_escape_string() to all fields

      //Then insert comment
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ($author,$postid,$body,$etc)");
      }
      else
      {
      die("Fill out everything please. Mkay.");
      }
      ?>

      id (auto incremented)
      name
      email
      text
      datetime
      approved--> */
}
    ?>
    <!--echo '--><div id="first">
        <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/emp-blast.jpg?type=square" height="42" width="42"/>
        <p>hamed1</p>
    </div><!--';-->
    <dl>
        <dt>comment1</dt>
        <dd>reply1</dd>
        <dd>reply2</dd>
    </dl>
    <!--//}
    /*else
    {

    }*/
    ?>-->
    <?php
    include 'Footer.php';
    ?>
```

My Comment class:

```
    <?php

include_once "DBConn.php";

class Comments extends DBConn {
    private $tableName = 'Comments';
    //attributes to represent table columns
    public $comment_Id = 0;
    public $Comment;
    public $UserName;
    public $Video_Id;
    public $Date_Time;

    public function save() {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {
            //escape any special characters
            $this->Comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->Comment);
            $this->UserName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->UserName);
            $this->Video_Id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->Video_Id);

            if ($this->comment_Id == null) {
                $q = 'INSERT INTO comments(Comment, User_Id, Video_Id, Date_Time) values' .
                        "('" . $this->Comment . "','" . $this->User_Id . "','" . $this->Video_Id . "',NOW()')";
            } else {
                $q = "update Comments set Comment='" . $this->Comment . "', Date_Time='" . NOW() ."'";
            }


            //   $q = "call SaveUser2($this->userId,'$this->firstName','$this->lastName','$this->email','$this->password')";

            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if (!$r) {
                $this->displayError($q);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

//end of function
    public function get($video_id) {
        if ($this->getDBConnection()) {

            $q = "SELECT Comment, Date_Time, UserName FROM Comments WHERE Video='" . $userName."' order by time_stamp";
            $r = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $q);

            if ($r) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r); 
                $this->Comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbc, $this->Comment);


                return true;
            }
            else
                $this->displayError($q);
        }
        else
            echo '<p class="error">Could not connect to database</p>';

        return false;
    }

    public function isValid() {
        //declare array to hold any errors messages  
        $errors = array();

        if (empty($this->Comment))
            $errors[] = 'You should enter a comment to be saved';
        return $errors;
    }
}
?>
```

Output show when I click insert button:

Not Found

The requested URL /IndividualProject/Comment.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Can you paste the output?

Comment: @LajosArpad Here I did bro

Comment: Try changing this line `(isset($_POST['submitted']))` to `(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Hamed, where is your Comment.php located in the project?

Comment: @LajosArpad in the same project folder where all my classes and other web pages are located

Comment: @claudios tried it, it didn't work

Comment: Hamed, how does your url look alike? If you look at the network tab of your console, where does it try to send the request?

Comment: When you write a question, can you please only write the parts that relevant. For example,I highly doubt that CSS is relevant! You'll get more good answers that way.

Comment: try loading the parent class construct

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this kind of issue when working on a staging site because webhosting may have different kinds of restrictions and strict. Now what I did is changing the filename for example:

Class name should match the filename coz it's case sensitive.

Comment.php

```
class Comment extends DBConn {

function __construct () {
parent::__construct ();
}

//code here..

 }
```